# Magento: The best way to hook into the checkout process

Tags: magento

I am integrating with a third party order management system and I have to make calls to it throughout the checkout process. The problem is, I don't think there are many events available because of how the onepage checkout is all done in javascript/ajax calls. There are a few like after saving the shipping method, and none of the dynamic events seem to fit either. basically I need to know as soon as the user is getting access to the shipping method tab to pass the billing shipping address over, then after the shipping method, to pass that over. Obviously there is an event for that. I know there are ones for when you submit an order so that should be good.

I guess I only need to know when the billing/shipping address is saved. I was using controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_onepage_progress but the progress gets called way to late. It just doesn't seem like there are a lot of hooks through the onepage checkout. if anyone can give me some examples of what they have done that would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't hook into the events of the checkout, hook into the events of the Models.  There's a

```
sales_quote_save_before
sales_quote_save_after
```

that you could hook into into and monitor for the addition of an address.

You could also hook into the general

```
model_save_before
model_save_after
```

actions and look for address objects.

You could also tap into the class override system and redefine one of the save methods on `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`.

Comment: I think I will do the quote way, I didn't really think of doing that because I figured there was a way to do it more directly. I think the best thing to do is to get the step data and seeing what is complete. I had already did something like that with my previous attempt. Thanks Alan!